# How to apply 2D chaining with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery, pipeline

I have the following tasks that I want to implement a pipeline for them

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from celery import Task
from django.core.paginator import Paginator


class PipelineTask(Task):

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class BaseStagingTask(PipelineTask):

    @abstractmethod
    def stage(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stage(*args, **kwargs)


class BaseLoadingTask(PipelineTask):

    @abstractmethod
    def load(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.load(*args, **kwargs)


class BaseFinalizingTask(PipelineTask):

    @abstractmethod
    def finalize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.finalize(*args, **kwargs)


class BasePipeline:

    def __init__(self, input_paginator, staging_tasks, loading_tasks, finalizing_tasks):
        """
        :type staging_tasks: List[StagingTask]
        :type loading_tasks: List[LoadingTask]
        :type finalizing_tasks: List[LoadingTask]
        :type input_paginator: django.core.paginator.Paginator
        """
        self.input_paginator = input_paginator
        self.staging_tasks = staging_tasks
        self.loading_tasks = loading_tasks
        self.finalizing_tasks = finalizing_tasks


    def run(self):
        pass
```

```
pipeline = BasePipeline(
    input_paginator= Paginator(some_queryset),
    staging_tasks=[s1,s2,s3],
    loading_tasks=[l1,l2,l3],
    finalizing_tasks=[f1,f2,f3]
)
pipeline.run()
```

I need to run the stages tasks in sequential order per data chunk, and at the same time, to run them in parallel across the entire data with the condition that each staging task start after the previous one finishes. It's depicted in the diagram below

[image]

I just need a pseudo-code to implement the above pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we don't need to use custom Task class.
As for the staging tasks, we can specify for each task a queue that runs one task at a time.

So the final workflow would be

```
group(
    chord(
        chains(s1, s2, s3),
        callback=chord(
            chain(l1, l2, l3),
            callback=group(f1, f2, f3)
        )
    )
)
```